# Open a modal from anchor tag but the content is from another page

Tags: bootstrap-modal, odoo, odoo-12

Is it possible to open a modal from anchor tag but the content is from another page? If yes, can anyone help me on how to do this? Btw I'm using Odoo, there is a default add to cart page in Odoo, so all code there was already default and I can't just get the content of the specific part from add to cart page and load it in my modal which is another page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a JS function to achieve this. When clicking on a button, you can listen to button click and show your modal accordingly. Odoo uses jQuery by default so you can call something like this.

```js
$(".button-class").click(function() {
  // do some stuff here
  // either do jsonRPC to get data from another record.
  // add values to the body
  // finally show your modal
  $(".modal-class").modal("show");
}
```